# CSS3 min-height property ignored with vertical-align: middle

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

http://codepen.io/maxwbailey/pen/nxaFr

I'm trying to get the text to center vertically. This is only important when there is white space (I.E. when the auto height would be less than min-height). How can I accomplish this? I've seen this question asked several times, but none of the answers I've yet found apply to my application.

Thanks! ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the fact that you've set a min-height of 75px, you can just add padding of half that to the top and bottom of the text, like so:

```
.warning {
  display:block;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 32.5px 0;
  /*vertical-align: middle;*/
}
```

`.warning` needs to be `display: block;` to accept padding, but those are the only changes that are necessary to accomplish your objective, I think. Check it out: http://codepen.io/maxwbailey/pen/qcvre

**EDIT**

If you want to keep the text centered until the container gets small enough that it fills the min-height, you need to use `display: table-cell`, like so:

```
.warning {
  display:table-cell;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 75px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/maxwbailey/pen/dwfar

Comment: Nope, I already thought of this. The problem here is that the padding is kept regardless of how much text is inside of the object. With the example text provided that is fine. However, once the amount of text would cause the object to reach a height of 75px or more anyway then the padding isn't serving as a work-around anymore it's serving as, well... ugly padding. :P

Comment: Ahh, I see. Updated my answer ^^

Comment: Also, for future reference, this is not a CSS3 issue, it's just a CSS issue. You'll have more luck if you tag all CSS questions with the CSS tag, as it has many more followers :)

Comment: Awesome, tyvm for the help! ^_^